# Overriding the sum values for the VennDiagram package

Tags: r, reshape2, venn-diagram

I have a dataset that kind of looks like this:

```
   ID    X   Y   Z   
1  T1    10  0   10 
2  T2    0   0   20 
3  T3    10  10  40
4  T4    0   30  10
5  T5    0   10  0 
...
```

I can melt down the data with reshape2 and throw it in the VennDiagram package to visualize the intersections of the dataset. But. I can only visualize counts (not sum totals).

VennDiagram will only recognize T1 as a "1" XZ intersection. I want the package to count "20". And for T3 it shouldn't be just "1" count of XYZ, I want it to sum to "60".

VennDiagram manual: [cran.r.project.org](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/VennDiagram/VennDiagram.pdf)

Thanks in advance!

Edit:

The output should look something like this...
Where the nrows will sum the totals together

(This current output will just grab the counts)

```
grid.newpage()
draw.triple.venn(area1 = nrow(subset(accounts, X > 1)),
             area2 = nrow(subset(accounts, Y > 1)), 
             area3 = nrow(subset(accounts, Z > 1)), 
             n12 = nrow(subset(accounts, X > 1 & Y > 1)), 
             n23 = nrow(subset(accounts, Y > 1 & Z > 1)), 
             n13 = nrow(subset(accounts, X > 1 & Z > 1)), 
             n123 = nrow(subset(accounts, X > 1 & Y > 1 & Z > 1)), 
             category = c("X", "Y", "Z"), 
             lty = "blank",
             fill = c("pink1","mediumorchid","skyblue"))
```

Comment: I'm a little confused about your expected output. What does the ID column signify. For `draw.triple.venn` in the `VennDiagram` package you are expecting the total A area to be 20, B to be 50, and C to be 80? How are you trying to calculate the intersections?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `library(VennDiagram)` package doesn't behave as you might expect it to behave.

You might have a table:

```
A1 A2 Overlap 
1  1  2
```

And you want the two venn diagram to reflect `1` in the left circle, `1` in the right circle and `2` in the overlap.

Running this code:

```
grid.newpage()
draw.pairwise.venn(area1 = 1,
                   area2 = 1,
                   cross.area = 2)
```

Will yield:

`Error in draw.pairwise.venn(area1 = 1, area2 = 1, cross.area = 2) : 
  Impossible: cross section area too large.`

So we have to cheat the venn diagram library by adding the overlap to each area. That way we will get the desired: 1;2;1.

```
grid.newpage()
draw.pairwise.venn(area1 = 1 +  2,
                   area2 = 1 +  2,
                   cross.area = 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use `sum` instead of `nrow`.  Also, you will want to watch your logic on the subsets and probably add conditions to `n12`, `n23`, and `n23`.

For example, for `n23` you will need: `Y > 1 & Z > 1 & X < 1` -- notice the addition of `X < 1`.  This should be closer to what you're after:

```
draw.triple.venn(area1 = sum(subset(accounts, X > 1)),
                 area2 = sum(subset(accounts, Y > 1)), 
                 area3 = sum(subset(accounts, Z > 1)), 
                 n12 = sum(subset(accounts, X > 1 & Y > 1 & Z < 1)), 
                 n23 = sum(subset(accounts, Y > 1 & Z > 1 & X < 1)), 
                 n13 = sum(subset(accounts, X > 1 & Z > 1 & Y < 1)), 
                 n123 = sum(subset(accounts, X > 1 & Y > 1 & Z > 1)), 
                 category = c("X", "Y", "Z"), 
                 lty = "blank",
                 fill = c("pink1","mediumorchid","skyblue"))
```

Comment: When I try to run your code I get:

Error in FUN(X[[1L]], ...) : only defined on a data frame with all numeric variables

Comment: Try removing the `Z < 1` from the `n12 =` line...This happens because you may be returning a data frame with no objects -- that is, the criteria results in a data frame with zero rows which will cause issues. There are probably better ways to error handle this.